# Geomesa TrackLabel WPS process

Tags: geomesa

I am trying to display the current position of every device registered in my geomesa-accumulo database through geoserver's WPS. Since each device sends its position every X seconds. I am using geomesa's TrackLabel process to get the last position of each device, the WPS process setup is:

```
track: device_id
dtg  : date_time
```

Using I run the process and display the results using leaflet. But, I think the results are not what I expected, because if I run the following query in jupyter notebook:

```
spark.sql("select device_id, date_time, position from positions where device_id = 145 order by date_time desc limit 1").show()
```

It returns that the last position was at **2016-05-17 20:47** but the TrackLabel process says **2016-03-05 20:12**.

My questions: If this the correct approach, then what am I missing?
              Or what should be the correct approach for this problem?

Comment: can you use the CLI tools to figure out what the correct value actually is?

Comment: Running the query again gives me the same results. But the TrackLabel process does not show the same position as the current one. Also, there are some device_id that does not appear in the TrackLabel json result.

Comment: can you use the geomesa CLI tools to validate, instead of spark sql? that should give a definitive answer.
`geomesa export ... --attributes date_time -q "device_id = 'foo'" | sort -r | head -n1`

Comment: Thanks for the cli example. I run the command and it outputs: 2016-05-17T20:47:13.000Z,145,15121874,POINT (-57.555508 -25.258156) as the last position, which is the same as SparkSQL output.

Comment: can you post the full XML you're using for the WPS?

Comment: Yes, the full WPS payload I am using can be found here https://pastebin.com/sJSpPWy9

Comment: I cloned geomesa repo in order to inspect TrackLabel process. I modified it to print one entry in the grouped map doing the following:  grouped.get(int2Integer(145)).foreach(f => print("SF: " + f + "\n")) the results of this is at https://pastebin.com/XTWsJdp1 it only shows 2015 data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155417/discussion-between-emilio-lahr-vivaz-and-jramirez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're querying the entire dataset, you may be hitting the WFS result limit. See [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/webadmin.html#features) for details

Comment: Thank to this hint and all the help in the chat, I implemented a solution where I first narrow the input data using geomesa:Query, and then use geomesa:TrackLabel process to figure out current positions in my database.